# how can i provide enemy tanks not to violate the wall borders properly?

Tags: java, collision

```java
  public boolean sagdancarpma() {
    boolean carpma=false;
    for(int i=0; i<br.solidBricksXPos.length;i++) {
        if(this.x==br.solidBricksXPos[i]+40&&(this.y+40>br.solidBricksYPos[i]&&this.y<br.solidBricksYPos[i]+40)) {
            carpma=true;
        }
    }return carpma; }
```

this is my collision detection. solid bricks are in another class. computer's tank are coded in this Dusman class. this code is for only collisions to the right side of the brick. tank is 40x40 pixels and bricks are 50x50.(i used 40 for brick because 50 didn't work.) sometimes "dusman"="enemy tanks passes through the bricks. i couldnt find an answer for this.

```java
 public void dusmantank() {
     for(int i=0; i<dusmanlar.size();i++)
     { Dusman d= dusmanlar.get(i); 
    if(d.say==0) {
        yonbelirle(d,d.getyon());
        d.say=random.nextInt(50);
    }
    if(d.yon1==1) {
        if(d.usttencarpma()) { 
            yonbelirle(d,1);
            
        }
        d.hrk(0,+1);
        d.say--;
        
    }
    if(d.yon1==2) {if(d.alttancarpma()) {
        yonbelirle(d,2);
        
    }
        d.hrk(0, -1);
        d.say--;
    }
    if(d.yon1==3) {
        if(d.soldancarpma()) {
         
            yonbelirle(d,3);
            
        }
    d.hrk(+1, 0);
        d.say--;
    
        }
    
    if(d.yon1==4) {
        if(d.sagdancarpma()) {
        yonbelirle(d,4);
        
    }
    d.hrk(-1, 0);
        d.say--;
    }
     
 }}
```

here is the codes for moving the enemy tanks automatically. yon1 means the direction of the tanks. after this if statement collision detection comes. if it is true "yonbelirle" method determines a random direction. i am a beginner so can you give me a simple  answer? thank u guys.

Comment: Welcome, hope I can help you :)
Did you try to return "carpma=true" right away? Otherwise, the next brick overrides the previous detected collision. A return statement would return the result right away and would not check other bricks.

Comment: thank you very much. i think i did it right. every bricks collision is detected by " for(int i=0; i<br.solidBricksXPos.length;i++)". his violation doesn't always happen.

Comment: If you think, that your hit detection might be faulty, you could try this: [Hit-testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-testing).